# To show that the lines laying on a smooth quadric in $\mathbb{P}_4$ form a closed irreducible subvariety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I need to show that the lines laying on a smooth quadric in $\mathbb{P}_4$ form a closed irreducible subvariety in the Grassmannian of all lines in $\mathbb{P}_4$, and then compute the dimension of this subvariety.

Any hint on how to tackle this? This question appeared in the final exam of my Algebraic Geometry course, and I was unable to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U$ be the tautological bundle on the Grassmannian. Then the equation of the quadric gives a global section of the bundle $S^2U^\vee$, and the desired subvariety $Z \subset Gr(2,5)$ is its zero locus (this proves it is a closed subvariety).

To prove irreducibility and to compute the dimension consider the projectivization $P_Z(U)$. It is a $P^1$-bundle over $Z$, so it is enough to prove irreducibility and to compute the dimension for it. Consider the natural map 
$$
P_Z(U) \to P^4.
$$ 
Clearly, its image is the quadric $Q$, and the fibers of this map parameterize lines on $Q$ passing through the given point. These fibers are easy to identify with smooth conics (bases of the cones which are the intersections of $Q$ with the tangent spaces at points). Therefore 
$$
P_Z(U) \to Q
$$ 
is also a $P^1$-bundle. In particular, it is irreducible, $\dim P_Z(U) = \dim Q + 1 = 4$, hence $Z$ is irreducible and $\dim Z = 4 - 1 = 3$.

Comment: Actually, if the base field is algebraically closed, $Z \cong \mathbb{P}^3$.